# Why do I get an 'Invalid namespace' error when attempting to use WMI?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, wmi, .net-4.5

I need to get the serial number of a hard drive to serve as a unique ID for user identification purposes, but however the program is crashing when I attempt to access the serial number:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.ManagementException' occurred in System.Management.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid namespace

I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be much on the issue; [one website](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459429-WMI-Invalid-Namespace-Error) mentions that 'WMI is like Death Valley', and I'm inclined to agree on this.

The error is occurring at `moHD.[Get]()`.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

The code:

```
Public Function getSerial(ByVal strDrive As String) As String 'Get HD Serial Number
    If strDrive = "" OrElse strDrive Is Nothing Then
        strDrive = "C"
    End If
    Dim moHD As New ManagementObject("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=""" + strDrive + ":""")
    moHD.[Get]()
    Return moHD("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: It's not about a deprecated API - it's about a subversion that's so scarce there's no need for a separate tag. Use .net-4.5 if you absolutely need a .net tag, but creating an entire tag for something that's nearly impossible to find on the interweebs is completely pointless. from the tag creation privilege: "**You should always favor existing tags**; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site." - 4.5 already exists, and so does 4.6 if that's more relevant.

Comment: @Zoe I didn't create that tag (unless it was burniated and me rolling back the edit re-created it, in which case I wasn't warned of this by the system), but I've edited my question to remove some fluff and to replace the tag with [tag:.net-4.5] (4.6 didn't exist when I asked this question, so don't see any reason to use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the namespace where the `Win32_LogicalDisk` class is located. Check this sample :

```
Public Function getSerial(ByVal strDrive As String) As String 'Get HD Serial Number
    If strDrive = "" OrElse strDrive Is Nothing Then
        strDrive = "C"
    End If

Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\.\root\cimv2")
Dim path As New ManagementPath("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=""" + strDrive + ":""")
Dim moHD  As New ManagementObject(scope, path, Nothing)
moHD.[Get]()
Return moHD("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: I get an `Value of type 'System.Management.ManagementPath' cannot be converted to 'System.Management.ObjectGetOptions'` error with that.

Comment: The code compiles, but now I'm back to the original error: http://puu.sh/eiaMp/33a2286671.png

Comment: I just tested the code and works fine, maybe the issue is the WMI repository, try rebuilding the WMI (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx)

Comment: Just tried the first version of the program and that crashes with the same error, too. The only thing I've changed on the OS is that I turned off Secure Boot in order to run test-signed drivers. Could be this. I don't need this anymore so I'm going to shut-down, go into the BIOS to switch it off then boot and see if that's done it.

Comment: I can confirm that it's the computer, I tried on another computer and it worked completely fine. I attempted to rebuild the WMI but it's telling me that it is consistent and when I try forcing it it says that it's failed because a system-critical service relies on it to function.

Comment: Just repaired the WMI with a third-party tool and now the problem's gone.